# How to distinguish between domains in JSP using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, url, request, jstl

I wanna distinguish between the requestUrl inside of a JSP and render different Content depending on the URL.

To be concret:

```
<c:set var="url" value="${pageContext.request.requestURL}" />
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${fn:contains(url, 'google.com')}">
    1 - Google.com
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    2 - Google.co.uk
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

In this case every time option 2 will be rendered. I really don't know why.

How can I do this the right way? Or is there a better way to do this in JSTL?

Cheers everyone

Comment: Did you include the `functions` tag library in your page?

Comment: Yes, the functionlib is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the first line to this:

```
<c:set var="url" value="${pageContext.request.requestURI}" />
```

**EDIT:** I forgot there's a getServerName() method also which should give you the requested host without the rest of the URL.  That's probably the better method to use.

getRequestURI() on HttpServletRequest returns a String while getRequestURL() returns a StringBuffer which doesn't have a contains method.

NOTE: I have not tested this code so ymmv.

Comment: Now I use `<c:when test="${fn:contains(pageContext.request.serverName, 'google.com')}">` And it works fine. Thanks for that.